# AWS Cognito Client ID configured for secret but secret was not received

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm adding up a user using AWS Cognito & have created a user pool id as well. But facing an error as mentioned in title.
`sign_up.py`

```
import os
from urllib import response
import boto3
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

username = "hello@abc.sh" #added the username create for aws account
password = "xyz@123" #added the password created for aws account

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name = os.getenv('COGNITO_REGION_NAME'))
response = client.sign_up(
    ClientId = os.getenv('COGNITO_USER_CLIENT_ID'),
    Username = username,
    Password = password
)
print(response)
```

Found a solution saying to uncheck the `Generate Client Secret` but it's not working & getting the error below
`botocore.errorfactory.NotAuthorizedException: An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the SignUp operation: Client XXX is configured for secret but secret was not received`

Comment: Suspect you need to calculate and supply the `SecretHash` when calling sign_up..

Comment: How can that be done. Could you please help/explain, as i'm an newbie.

Comment: See [How To create a SecretHash value](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-unable-to-verify-secret-hash/).

Comment: @jarmod thank you. I'll go through the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
from urllib import response
import boto3
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

username = "hello@abc.sh" #added the username create for aws account
password = "xyz@123" #added the password created for aws account

def get_secret_hash(username):
    msg = username + os.getenv('COGNITO_USER_CLIENT_ID')
    dig = hmac.new(str(os.getenv('COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET')).encode('utf-8'),
                   msg=str(msg).encode('utf-8'), 
                   digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    d2 = base64.b64encode(dig).encode()
    return d2
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name = os.getenv('COGNITO_REGION_NAME'))
response = client.sign_up(
    ClientId = os.getenv('COGNITO_USER_CLIENT_ID'),
    Username = username,
    Password = password,
    SecretHash = get_secret_hash(username)
)
print(response)
```